# Image and text underneath each other instead of side by side (minipage)

Tags: minipage

I try to use the package minipage to put an image and a text side by side. Usually it works but here it shows underneath each other. Is there anything I could do?

Here is the code (sorry it's french content) :

```
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Skieur.png}
\captionof{figure}{Schéma de la situation (à recopier sur votre feuille)}
\label{fig:figure}
\end{minipage} \qquad

\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Rappeler le principe d'inertie. (2 points)
\begin{warning}
Penser à bien préciser les hypothèses nécessaires pour l'appliquer!
\end{warning}
\item Effectuer un bilan des forces pour le skieur. (4 points)
\begin{warning}
Ne pas oublier de représenter ces forces sur un schéma !
\end{warning}
\textit{\underline{Remarque :}
On pourra regrouper la force de frottement fluide (celle de l'air sur le skieur) et la force de frottement solide (celle de la neige sur les skis) en une seule et même force, appelée $\overrightarrow{F_f}$ qui s'applique au centre de gravité du skieur.}
\item Appliquer le principe d'inertie pour obtenir l'équation vectorielle qui régit le mouvement du skieur. (4 points)
\item \textbf{BONUS} (beaucoup plus difficile): En projetant successivement selon 2 directions (axe $x$ puis axe $y$) trouver la valeur de la tension produit par la perche et la  valeur de la réaction exercée par la piste
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}\qquad
```

Here is the picture of the problem :

[image]

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Try to remove the qquad and the blank lines. If this works you can add an `\hfill`

Comment: There isn't a *package* `minipage` on CTAN. Did you mean, the *environment* `minipage` without using an extra package? To avoid misunderstandings, it would always be a good idea to not only show a code snippet but a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thank you BanDop. It actually works when removing qquad and the blank lines!

Comment: @BanDoP: Can you write up an answer?

Comment: sure, please see below.

Answer (score 1):

While [BanDop's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701951/) identifies a suitable solution, it misidentifies the cause and presents sufficient changes as necessary.

The fundamental problem isn't that the blank line adds blank space or that this additional blank space plus the `\qquad` and the total width of the `\minipage`s exceeds `\textwidth`. It's that the blank line inserts a paragraph break. Indeed, a blank line just is the mark up used to indicate a paragraph break in TeX, LaTeX etc. Even if the `minipage`s were only `.01\textwidth` wide, you'd still get the one typeset above the other.

Indeed, it is not necessary to remove either the `\qquad` or the preceding space. It is quite sufficient to remove the paragraph break by commenting the blank line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{warning}{}{}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Skieur.png}
  \captionof{figure}{Schéma de la situation (à recopier sur votre feuille)}
  \label{fig:figure}
\end{minipage} \qquad
% 
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Rappeler le principe d'inertie. (2 points)
    \begin{warning}
      Penser à bien préciser les hypothèses nécessaires pour l'appliquer!
    \end{warning}
    \item Effectuer un bilan des forces pour le skieur. (4 points)
    \begin{warning}
      Ne pas oublier de représenter ces forces sur un schéma !
    \end{warning}
    \textit{\underline{Remarque :}
      On pourra regrouper la force de frottement fluide (celle de l'air sur le skieur) et la force de frottement solide (celle de la neige sur les skis) en une seule et même force, appelée $\overrightarrow{F_f}$ qui s'applique au centre de gravité du skieur.}
    \item Appliquer le principe d'inertie pour obtenir l'équation vectorielle qui régit le mouvement du skieur. (4 points)
    \item \textbf{BONUS} (beaucoup plus difficile): En projetant successivement selon 2 directions (axe $x$ puis axe $y$) trouver la valeur de la tension produit par la perche et la  valeur de la réaction exercée par la piste
  \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}\qquad
\end{document}
```

[image: side-by-side with extant \qquad]

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your document is that LaTeX added additional whitespace between the two minipage environments due to the empty line. Together with the `\qquad`and the 2 x `0.45\linewidth` the total witdth is larger than the `\linewidth`. Removing `\qquad` as well as the empty line (e.g., by adding a comment symbol` should solve the problem.

```tex
% ...
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
% ...
```

If you want to use all the remaining space and put it in between the two minipages, pushing them to the left and right margin, you can use `\hfill`, e.g.,

```tex
% ...
\end{minipage}
%
\hfill
%
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
% ...
```

Comment: It isn't necessary to remove the `\qquad` because the problem isn't the total width but the paragraph break.